# How to sanitize user input in Cakephp3 through out the application

Tags: cakephp, sanitize

In our ***Cakephp3*** application, the user is inputting some text with apostrophe's and it should be backslashed or using mysql_real_escape_string() we should be handled to override the errors throwing in site.

This fix should be done in one uniq place, instead of being taken care in all the places.

What would be the best approach?
Thanks

Comment: When used correctly, the query builder/compiler will properly bind the data so that the driver escapes it accordingly - usually there should be no need to manipulate input like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommed you to put a str_replace at your tables before marshall.

If this is needed for all tables, I recommend you to put the before marshall at Table.php and extend it in yours others tables

It should be something like this:

At table.php:

```
public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, ArrayObject $data, 
ArrayObject $options)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_string($value)) {
            $data[$key] = str_replace("'","`",$value);
        }
    }
}
```

At the other tables:

```
class YourTableNameTable extends Table
```

Read the following: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#modifying-request-data-before-building-entities

Comment: I hope this would be a nice idea. Thanks.

Comment: This is not needed, the opposite: This harms more than it does good. Follow the given advice above as well as [this](https://www.dereuromark.de/2010/10/05/cakephp-security/) and you are good.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I reinventing the wheel, but cake provides methods to correctly save and display any data which user tries to "inject".

In trivial case, if the user wanna save his nickname as `105; DROP TABLE users` or `<script>location.href="pornhub"</script>` - You should allow him to use that nickname, and if You use standard model - there's no way to inject anything. When You try to display users data back in the layout, just use `h($user->nickname)`

Comment: Can you provide references for your assumption?